# Powershell Copy-file and create-folder to remote machines with different credentials

Tags: powershell

All the machines have the same local admin account and password.

Here is what I have so far.

My script:

```
$computers = gc "C:\tmp\computers.txt"
$source = "C:\Folder\"
$dest = "c$\Folder\"
$creds = Get-Credential

foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
    if (test-Connection -Cn $computer -quiet)
    {
        New-PSDrive -Name Y -PSProvider filesystem -Root "\\$computer\$dest" -Credential $creds
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name "Folder" -Path "\\$computer\c$" -Credential $creds
        Copy-Item $source -Destination Y:\ -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable A
        if($A) { write-Output "$computer - File copy Failed" | out-file "C:\tmp\_Copy.txt" -Append }
        Remove-PSDrive Y
    }
    else
    {   Write-Output "$computer is offline" | Out-File "C:\tmp\_Copy_error.txt" -Append
    }
}
```

Output :

```
New-PSDrive : The network name cannot be found
At line:10 char:3
+         New-PSDrive -Name Y -PSProvider filesystem -Root "\\$computer ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Y:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotMapNetworkDrive,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand
 
New-Item : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. The FileSystem provider supports credentials only on the New-PSDrive cmdlet. Perform the 
operation again without specifying credentials.
At line:11 char:9
+         New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name "Folder" -Path "\\$comp ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDynamicParametersException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
 
Remove-PSDrive : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'Y' does not exist.
At line:14 char:3
+         Remove-PSDrive Y
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Y:String) [Remove-PSDrive], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemovePSDriveCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

How the computer names are laid out in the TXT file? Is it one name per line, or separated by something like a ','?
Other observations:

If you are trying to create a folder named 'Folder' on the remote PC, the path "\$computer\C$\Folder" does not exist yet, thus the error.

Try something like this:

```
$computers = Get-Content -Path "C:\tmp\computers.txt"
$source = "C:\Folder\"
$creds = Get-Credential

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    if (test-Connection -Cn $computer -quiet) {

        # We are creating the PSDrive at C:\ on the remote PC.
        New-PSDrive -Name Y -PSProvider filesystem -Root "\\$computer\C$" -Credential $creds

        # Since we have a PSDrive, we don't need to use the UNC format, just use the new drive.
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name "Folder" -Path 'Y:\' -Credential $creds

        # Now that we have a drive and a folder, we copy into it.
        Copy-Item $source -Destination 'Y:\Folder' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable A
        if($A) { write-Output "$computer - File copy Failed" | out-file "C:\tmp\_Copy.txt" -Append }
        Remove-PSDrive Y
    }
    else {   Write-Output "$computer is offline" | Out-File "C:\tmp\_Copy_error.txt" -Append
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!